# curl command to close all indices at once in elastic search

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, backup, restore

I am restoring the snapshot in elastic search cluster but before restoring, I need to close all the open indices. The command to close the index that I found is `curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/twitter/_close"` which closes only one index `twitter`. I have a long list of open indices and invoking this command each time, is not a feasible solution. Does anyone has any idea to make it more easier?

Answer (score 10):

```
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/_all/_close"
```

use `_all` to select all indexes.

Comment: Are there any additional changes need to do as after executing this command I am getting the following error-`{"error":"RemoteTransportException[[Bobster][inet[/10.20.35.2:9300]][indices:admin/close]]; nested: IndexMissingException[[_all] missing]; ","status":404}`

Comment: which elasticsearch are you using? it doesn't support **0.9.X** version, see:   official document: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/indices-open-close.html

Comment: version is  1.6.X

Comment: Getting "Wildcard expressions or all indices are not allowed" on ES 8

Comment: Hi @Sergey, you should check  elasticsearch.yml whether config: action.destructive_requires_name to true, if you want to enable delete by `_all` or  `wildcard` should set to false, find more:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-management-settings.html

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html), you can close all indexes with:

```
$ curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/_all/_close"
```

If you get an error regarding missing indexes, you can ignore them with the following parameters:

```
$ curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/_all/_close?allow_no_indices=true&expand_wildcards=all"
```

Answer (score 3):

This solved my issue:

`curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/_all/_close"`

Snapshot was not getting restored, and throwing `SnapshotRestoreException`.